# Spring autowire by name

Tags: java, spring

Consider I want to autowire beans by name.

**Sample interface:**

```
@FunctionalInterface
private interface TestQualifier {
    void test();
}
```

I have two options when defining my beans.

**Option #1:**

Using `@Qualifier` on top of `@Bean` definitions.

```
@Configuration
public class QualifierConfig {

    @Bean()
    @Qualifier("first")
    public TestQualifier first() {
        return () -> System.out.println("first");
    }

    @Bean()
    @Qualifier("second")
    public TestQualifier second() {
        return () -> System.out.println("second");
    }

}
```

**Option #2:**

Using the `name` parameter of the `@Bean` annotation.

```
@Configuration
public class QualifierConfig {

    @Bean(name = "first")
    public TestQualifier first() {
        return () -> System.out.println("first");
    }

    @Bean(name = "second")
    public TestQualifier second() {
        return () -> System.out.println("second");
    }

}
```

In both cases, I am able to autowire by name. Invoking the `testAutowiring()` method produces the expected results.

```
@Component
public class MyComponent {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("first")
    private TestQualifier first;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("second")
    private TestQualifier second;

    public void testAutowiring() {
        first.test();
        second.test();
    }

}
```

Output:

> first
>
> second

**My questions are:**

1. Which is the recommended approach when defining beans that will be autowired by name?
2. **Does one approach have any advantages over the other**, or is it entirely a matter of taste?

Thanks!

Comment: usually `@Qualifier` is used when u want to autowire an interface and u have more than one bean in your application context that is the interface child.

Comment: option #3: Don't put anything because `@Bean(name)` docs: "If left unspecified, the name of the bean is the name of the annotated method. If specified, the method name is ignored." Would not do that though, name should be intentional.

Answer (score 2):

I would go for `@Bean` annotation:

1.It is the stronger one. If you add both `@Bean("abc")` and `@Qualifier("b")` the "abc" name will win.

2.You can add multiple bean identifiers for the same bean. `@Qualifier` does not have this property.

Example:

```
@Bean({"ab", "bc"})
public MyBean myBean() {
  return new MyBean();
}
```

In this case the bean can be accessed with both Qualifiers "ab" and "bc".

3.`@Qualifier` has the main purpose to identify a bean and `@Bean` has the main purpose to construct and initialize a bean, including it's identifiers.